# /data's data is garbled in TWRP. How to decrypt

Tags: twrp, data-recovery, fastboot, encryption, partitions

So  this is quite another `android` story but I promise to keep is as short n dry as poss.
The issue was some of my Apps weren't able to access  /extsd folders with non root & so I deicided to give `magisk module` app `systematizer` a shot. With that also installed Pixel3fy  ( or whatever heck its called ) & & `Viper4Android`  
 I dunno if that has any bearing. Removed Pixel after I booted on a blank screen and data got `encrypted` ( due to that Pixel Mod ? No sure. I can mount /data but all file names under L1 folders are `encrypted` aka garbled  ) . I am running  `Q Havoc` on top of `TWRP`  on `Qualcomm` chip mobile . Earlier , TWRP would ask me my pattern and `decrypt` `/data` and `/system` and I had access to these via `TWRP`. Now ( related to Mod installation ? ), it does NOT ask me for pattern and I can mount these partitions but they remain encrypted. I want my `internal data` . So `Format` `/data` is not an op.
**What I did:**

-- reinstalled this `TWRP + Vmeta via Fastboot`.( hoping that the pattern will come back again but went futile ) After that no OS load. Just reboots to `TWRP`
-- Followed this by installing boot.img + magisk zip again and Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt zip

after all this it could BOOT TO LOGO and then HANGS ON LOGO
**Questions :**

-- How do I get TWRP to decrypt /data ( esp int. storage ) .After that I dont mind doing a fresh install after /data format . I want my int data.
--alternatively how can I successfully boot any way so I can backup my internal data
-- take a look at [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-3/how-to/unencrypt-oxygenos-loosing-data-t3412228), where he says you can  `decrypt` data by `backup` --> `format` --> `restore`. But `/data` is `encrypted` so backup and restore ...isn't it futile ? if I backup this data some form. My understanding is that its useless cos its `encrypted` and  restore will be fruitless since the data is encrypted with Unlock pin + key stored in Meta partition. I dont have any more backup. My last Nandroid was of stock rom. The `/recovery /vendor`  are same `/system` and `/data` are not. I in fact tried `/recovery` `Nandroid` restore - no use 

After that I  can do a 'format' and get my OS working. 

A subtle clarification. Once I removed the `Pix3ly` module I could boot the phone. `TWRP`  would not decrypt data after I tried command line

```
adb decrypt twrp <pattern>
```

I  thoughtlessly shot myself in the foot by not backing up  my `partitions` via `TWRP` and ended up doing a `TWRP` reinstall, which is when I got stuck-> will only boot to recovery --> ( `flashboot boot.img + Magisk` ) --> Now it will not reboot to `recovery` but stuck at Logo. Thats where I am now.
So yes any potentially offending module was removed  and that got me to boot but TWRP re-installation hosed everything. Desperate not to loose data I installed orange fox recovery to see if that can `decrypt` ( of course never had hi Hopes ) and still no light . 
 `stock recovery` cant handle `Havoc`. Stock ROM is `Pie` and this is Q so that wont match and even then issue is `/data` is not getting `decrypted` so any ROM wont boot is my humble , nimble  understanding but do let me know if there's something that can work

```
    Starting TWRP 3.3.1-milankragujevic_9.0_v1-8c0bcc8b on Sun May 31 06:29:22 1970
 (pid 406)
I:=> product model: 'Redmi (A'
I:=> using device id: 'Redmi_A'
BOARD_HAS_NO_REAL_SDCARD := true
RECOVERY_SDCARD_ON_DATA := true
I:Lun file '/sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_mass_storage/lun0/file' does not exist, USB storage mode disabled
TW_INCLUDE_CRYPTO := true
I:Found brightness file at '/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness'
I:Got max brightness 2047 from '/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/max_brightness'
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 2047
I:LANG: en
Starting the UI...
setting DRM_FORMAT_RGBX8888 and GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBX_8888
cannot find/open a drm device: No such file or directory
fb0 reports (possibly inaccurate):
  vi.bits_per_pixel = 32
  vi.red.offset   =   0   .length =   8
  vi.green.offset =   8   .length =   8
  vi.blue.offset  =  16   .length =   8
setting GGL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
double buffered
framebuffer: 0 (720 x 1520)
Using fbdev graphics.
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 2047
I:Loading package: splash (/twres/splash.xml)
I:Load XML directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/splash.xml' directly
I:Checking resolution...
I:Scaling theme width 0.666667x and height 0.791667x, offsets x: 0 y: 0 w: 0 h: 0
I:Loading resources...
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Loading page splash
I:Switching packages (splash)
=> Linking mtab
=> Processing /etc/recovery.fstab
I:Reading /etc/recovery.fstab
I:Processing '/boot'
I:Processing '/recovery'
I:Processing '/system_root'
I:Created '/system_root' folder.
I:Processing '/system_image'
I:Processing '/vendor'
I:Processing '/vendor_image'
I:Processing '/data'
I:Processing '/cache'
I:Processing '/cust'
I:Created '/cust' folder.
I:Processing '/misc'
I:Processing '/external_sd'
I:Created '/external_sd' folder.
I:Done processing fstab files
I:Setting up '/data' as data/media emulated storage.
I:mount -o bind '/data/media' '/sdcard' process ended with RC=0
I:mount -o bind '/data/media/0' '/sdcard' process ended with RC=0
I:File Based Encryption is present
e4crypt_initialize_global_de
Determining wrapped-key support for /data
fbe.data.wrappedkey = false
calling retrieveAndInstallKey
Key exists, using: /data/unencrypted/key
Using Keymaster HAL: 4 from QTI for encryption.  Security level: TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT, HAL: android.hardware.keymaster@4.0::IKeymasterDevice/default
begin failed, code -62
Upgrading key in memory only: /data/unencrypted/key
upgrade_key failed, code -38
e4crypt_initialize_global_de returned fail
e4crypt_initialize_global_de
Determining wrapped-key support for /data
fbe.data.wrappedkey = false
calling retrieveAndInstallKey
Key exists, using: /data/unencrypted/key
Using Keymaster HAL: 4 from QTI for encryption.  Security level: TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT, HAL: android.hardware.keymaster@4.0::IKeymasterDevice/default
begin failed, code -62
Upgrading key in memory only: /data/unencrypted/key
upgrade_key failed, code -38
e4crypt_initialize_global_de returned fail
e4crypt_initialize_global_de
Determining wrapped-key support for /data
fbe.data.wrappedkey = false
calling retrieveAndInstallKey
Key exists, using: /data/unencrypted/key
Using Keymaster HAL: 4 from QTI for encryption.  Security level: TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT, HAL: android.hardware.keymaster@4.0::IKeymasterDevice/default
begin failed, code -62
Upgrading key in memory only: /data/unencrypted/key
upgrade_key failed, code -38
e4crypt_initialize_global_de returned fail
I:Setting up '/data' as data/media emulated storage.
I:mount -o bind '/data/media/0' '/sdcard' process ended with RC=0
I:Backup folder set to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/Redmi_A'
I:Settings storage is '/data/media/0'
I:Decrypt adopted storage starting
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/data/system/storage.xml' directly
I:No /data/system/storage.xml for adopted storage
Updating partition details...
I:App found at '/system_root/system/priv-app/twrpapp'
I:Data backup size is 9887MB, free: 9730MB.
...done
I:Unmounting main partitions...

Partition Logs:
/boot | /dev/block/mmcblk0p52 | Size: 64MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p52
   Display_Name: Boot
   Storage_Name: boot
   Backup_Path: /boot
   Backup_Name: boot
   Backup_Display_Name: Boot
   Storage_Path: /boot
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/recovery | /dev/block/mmcblk0p53 | Size: 64MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p53
   Display_Name: Recovery
   Storage_Name: recovery
   Backup_Path: /recovery
   Backup_Name: recovery
   Backup_Display_Name: Recovery
   Storage_Path: /recovery
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/system_root | /dev/block/mmcblk0p59 | Size: 4092MB Used: 1453MB Free: 2638MB Backup Size: 1453MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p59
   Display_Name: System
   Storage_Name: System
   Backup_Path: /system_root
   Backup_Name: system_root
   Backup_Display_Name: System
   Storage_Path: /system_root
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/system_image | /dev/block/mmcblk0p59 | Size: 4096MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p59
   Display_Name: System Image
   Storage_Name: System Image
   Backup_Path: /system_image
   Backup_Name: system_image
   Backup_Display_Name: System Image
   Storage_Path: /system_image
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/vendor | /dev/block/mmcblk0p60 | Size: 975MB Used: 672MB Free: 303MB Backup Size: 672MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent Mount_Read_Only 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p60
   Display_Name: Vendor
   Storage_Name: Vendor
   Backup_Path: /vendor
   Backup_Name: vendor
   Backup_Display_Name: Vendor
   Storage_Path: /vendor
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/vendor_image | /dev/block/mmcblk0p60 | Size: 1024MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Backed_Up IsPresent Can_Flash_Img 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p60
   Display_Name: Vendor Image
   Storage_Name: Vendor Image
   Backup_Path: /vendor_image
   Backup_Name: vendor_image
   Backup_Display_Name: Vendor Image
   Storage_Path: /vendor_image
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/data | /dev/block/mmcblk0p62 | Size: 21916MB Used: 9887MB Free: 9730MB Backup Size: 9887MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_During_Factory_Reset Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent Can_Be_Encrypted Has_Data_Media Can_Encrypt_Backup Use_Userdata_Encryption Is_Storage Is_Settings_Storage 
   Symlink_Path: /data/media/0
   Symlink_Mount_Point: /sdcard
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p62
   Crypto_Key_Location: footer
   Display_Name: Data
   Storage_Name: Internal Storage
   Backup_Path: /data
   Backup_Name: data
   Backup_Display_Name: Data
   Storage_Path: /data/media/0
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65537

/cache | /dev/block/mmcblk0p57 | Size: 355MB Used: 0MB Free: 355MB Backup Size: 0MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_During_Factory_Reset Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p57
   Display_Name: Cache
   Storage_Name: Cache
   Backup_Path: /cache
   Backup_Name: cache
   Backup_Display_Name: Cache
   Storage_Path: /cache
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/cust | /dev/block/mmcblk0p61 | Size: 802MB Used: 298MB Free: 503MB Backup Size: 298MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Can_Be_Backed_Up Wipe_Available_in_GUI IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p61
   Display_Name: Custom
   Storage_Name: Custom
   Backup_Path: /cust
   Backup_Name: cust
   Backup_Display_Name: Custom
   Storage_Path: /cust
   Current_File_System: ext4
   Fstab_File_System: ext4
   Backup_Method: files

/misc | /dev/block/mmcblk0p30 | Size: 1MB
   Flags: IsPresent 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk0p30
   Display_Name: misc
   Storage_Name: misc
   Backup_Path: /misc
   Backup_Name: misc
   Backup_Display_Name: misc
   Storage_Path: /misc
   Current_File_System: emmc
   Fstab_File_System: emmc
   Backup_Method: dd

/external_sd | /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 | Size: 30161MB Used: 11029MB Free: 19131MB Backup Size: 11029MB
   Flags: Can_Be_Mounted Can_Be_Wiped Wipe_Available_in_GUI Removable IsPresent Is_Storage 
   Primary_Block_Device: /dev/block/mmcblk1p1
   Display_Name: External SD
   Storage_Name: External SD
   Backup_Path: /external_sd
   Backup_Name: external_sd
   Backup_Display_Name: External SD
   Storage_Path: /external_sd
   Current_File_System: f2fs
   Fstab_File_System: vfat
   Backup_Method: files
   MTP_Storage_ID: 65538

I:Loading package: TWRP (/data/media/0/TWRP/theme/ui.zip)
I:Loading zip theme
I:Loading package: TWRP (/twres/ui.xml)
I:Load XML directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/cz.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/de.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/el.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/en.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/es.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/fr.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/hu.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/it.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/nl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pt_BR.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/pt_PT.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/ru.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sk.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sl.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/sv.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/tr.xml' directly
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/uk.xml' directlyparsing languageFileparsing languageFile done
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/ui.xml' directly
I:Checking resolution...
I:Scaling theme width 0.666667x and height 0.791667x, offsets x: 0 y: 0 w: 0 h: 0
I:Loading resources...
I:Failed to load image from indeterminate013, error -1
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Including file: /twres/portrait.xml...
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/portrait.xml' directly
I:Loading resources...
I:Loading variables...
I:Loading mouse cursor...
I:Loading pages...
I:Loading page main
I:Loading page main2
I:Loading page install
I:Loading page flash_confirm
I:Loading page flash_zip
I:Loading page flash_done
I:Loading page flash_sleep_and_reboot
I:Loading page flashimage_confirm
I:Loading page clear_vars
I:Loading page reboot_system_routine
I:Loading page confirm_action
I:Loading page action_page
I:Loading page singleaction_page
I:Loading page action_complete
I:Loading page filecheck
I:Loading page rebootcheck
I:Loading page appcheck
I:Loading page wipe
I:Loading page advancedwipe
I:Loading page formatdata
I:Loading page formatdata_confirm
I:Loading page checkpartitionlist
I:Loading page partitionoptions
I:Loading page refreshfilesystem
I:Loading page selectfilesystem
I:Loading page backup
I:Loading page backup_options
I:Loading page backupname1
I:Loading page backupname2
I:Loading page backupencryption
I:Loading page backupencryption2
I:Loading page checkbackuppassword
I:Loading page backup_run
I:Loading page restore
I:Unable to open '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/Redmi_A'
I:Loading page restore_read
I:Loading page restore_decrypt
I:Loading page try_restore_decrypt
I:Loading page restore_select
I:Loading page renamebackup
I:Loading page restore_run
I:Loading page mount
I:Loading page usb_mount
I:Loading page usb_umount
I:Loading page system_readonly_check
I:Loading page reboot
I:Loading page rebootapp
I:Loading page system_readonly
I:Loading page settings
I:Loading page settings_timezone
I:Loading page settings_screen
I:Loading page settings_vibration
I:Loading page settings_language
I:Loading page copylog
I:Loading page advanced
I:Loading page partsdcardsel
I:Loading page partsdcardcheck
I:Loading page partsdcard
I:Loading page htcdumlock
I:Loading page repackselect
I:Loading page repackconfirm
I:Loading page lock
I:Loading page filemanagerlist
I:Loading page filemanageroptions
I:Loading page choosedestinationfolder
I:Loading page filemanagerrenamefile
I:Loading page filemanagerrenamefolder
I:Loading page filemanagerchmod
I:Loading page filemanagerconfirm
I:Loading page filemanageraction
I:Loading page decrypt
I:Loading page decrypt_pattern
I:Loading page trydecrypt
I:Loading page terminalcommand
I:Loading page sideload
I:Loading page fixcontexts
I:Loading page slideout
I:Loading page select_storage
I:Loading page select_language
I:Set page: 'clear_vars'
I:Set page: 'main2'
I:Switching packages (TWRP)
Startup Commands: 
ro.boottime.adbd=3507457029
ro.boottime.init=3078
ro.boottime.init.selinux=111
ro.boottime.init.cold_boot_wait=181
ro.boottime.logd=3484639790
ro.boottime.ueventd=3290798384
ro.boottime.qseecomd=3514871769
ro.boottime.recovery=3488612394
ro.boottime.keymaster-4-0=3581855571
ro.boottime.gatekeeper-1-0=3582846248
ro.boottime.servicemanager=3583835988
ro.boottime.set_permissive=3487782759
ro.boottime.hwservicemanager=3476452186
ro.config.ringtone=omni_ringtone1.ogg,omni_ringtone1.ogg
ro.config.alarm_alert=omni_alarm1.ogg
ro.config.notification_sound=omni_notification1.ogg
dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant=cortex-a15
dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features=default
dalvik.vm.dexopt.secondary=true
dalvik.vm.usejit=true
dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold=500
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms=64m
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx=512m
dalvik.vm.appimageformat=lz4
dalvik.vm.usejitprofiles=true
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-dir=/data/anr
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xms=64m
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-Xmx=64m
dalvik.vm.image-dex2oat-filter=verify-at-runtime
dalvik.vm.dex2oat-minidebuginfo=true
debug.atrace.tags.enableflags=0
ro.art.hiddenapi.warning=1
ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-google
ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist=GoogleGuest
ro.opa.eligible_device=true
ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
ro.boot.dp=0x0
ro.boot.emmc=true
ro.boot.efuse=1
ro.boot.console=ttyMSM0
ro.boot.selinux=permissive
ro.boot.baseband=msm
ro.boot.configfs=true
ro.boot.dtbo_idx=6
ro.boot.hardware=qcom
ro.boot.keymaster=1
ro.boot.bootdevice=7824900.sdhci
ro.boot.secureboot=1
ro.boot.avb_version=1.1
ro.boot.usbconfigfs=true
ro.boot.verifiedbootstate=orange
ro.omni.device=olivelite
ro.omni.version=9-20191120-olivelite-HOMEMADE
ro.omni.version.security_patch=
ro.twrp.boot=1
ro.twrp.version=3.3.1-milankragujevic_9.0_v1
ro.vndk.lite=true
ro.vndk.version=28
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.allow.mock.location=1
ro.build.id=PQ3B.190801.002
ro.build.date=Wed Nov 20 16:49:01 CET 2019
ro.build.date.utc=1574264941
ro.build.host=milan-laptop
ro.build.tags=test-keys
ro.build.type=eng
ro.build.user=milan
ro.build.flavor=omni_olivelite-eng
ro.build.display.id=omni_olivelite-eng 9 PQ3B.190801.002 eng.milan.20191120.164901 test-keys
ro.build.product=olivelite
ro.build.selinux=1
ro.build.version.sdk=28
ro.build.version.base_os=
ro.build.version.release=9
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.incremental=eng.milan.20191120.164901
ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0
ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL
ro.build.version.security_patch=2099-12-31
ro.build.version.min_supported_target_sdk=17
ro.build.description=omni_olivelite-eng 9 PQ3B.190801.002 eng.milan.20191120.164901 test-keys
ro.build.characteristics=default
ro.bionic.ld.warning=1
ro.kernel.android.checkjni=1
ro.secure=0
ro.treble.enabled=true
ro.zygote=zygote32
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist=armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist64=
ro.product.name=omni_olivelite
ro.product.brand=Xiaomi
ro.product.model=Redmi (A
ro.product.device=olivelite
ro.product.locale=en-US
ro.product.manufacturer=Xiaomi
ro.baseband=msm
ro.bootmode=unknown
ro.hardware=qcom
ro.revision=0
ro.services.whitelist.packagelist=com.google.android.gms
ro.bootimage.build.date=Wed Nov 20 16:49:01 CET 2019
ro.bootimage.build.date.utc=1574264941
ro.bootimage.build.fingerprint=Xiaomi/omni_olivelite/olivelite:9/PQ3B.190801.002/milan11201649:eng/test-keys
ro.bootloader=unknown
ro.debuggable=1
ro.modversion=OmniROM-9-20191120-olivelite-HOMEMADE
ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode=1
ro.property_service.version=2
ro.control_privapp_permissions=enforce
ro.actionable_compatible_property.enabled=false
init.svc.adbd=running
init.svc.logd=running
init.svc.ueventd=running
init.svc.qseecomd=running
init.svc.recovery=running
init.svc.keymaster-4-0=running
init.svc.gatekeeper-1-0=running
init.svc.servicemanager=running
init.svc.set_permissive=stopped
init.svc.hwservicemanager=running
twrp.crash_counter=0
twrp.action_complete=0
crypto.ready=1
tombstoned.max_tombstone_count=50
sys.usb.ffs.ready=1
ro.build.fingerprint=Xiaomi/omni_olivelite/olivelite:9/PQ3B.190801.002/milan11201649:eng/test-keys
hwservicemanager.ready=true
log.tag.stats_log=I
ro.logd.size.stats=64K
ro.persistent_properties.ready=true
pm.dexopt.boot=extract
pm.dexopt.ab-ota=speed-profile
pm.dexopt.shared=speed
pm.dexopt.install=speed-profile
pm.dexopt.inactive=verify
pm.dexopt.bg-dexopt=speed-profile
pm.dexopt.first-boot=extract
ro.boot.serialno=39b2a4210606
ro.serialno=39b2a4210606
service.adb.root=1
net.bt.name=Android
net.tethering.noprovisioning=true
sys.usb.state=mtp,adb
sys.usb.controller=msm_hsusb
persist.sys.usb.config=adb
persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2=libart.so
persist.sys.disable_rescue=true
sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
ro.vendor.build.security_patch=2099-12-31
vendor.sys.listeners.registered=true
ro.crypto.type=file
ro.crypto.state=encrypted

SELinux contexts loaded from /file_contexts
Full SELinux support is present.
tw_get_context got selinux context: u:object_r:media_rw_data_file:s0
I:Got default contexts and file mode for storage files.
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Pre-fix date and time: 1970-05-31--06-29-29
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: Setting time offset from file /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/since_epoch
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: will attempt to use the ats files now.
I:TWFunc::Fixup_Time: no ats files found, leaving untouched!
I:Copied file /cache/recovery/log.gz to /cache/recovery/last_log.gz
I:Attempt to load settings from settings file...
I:InfoManager file '/data/media/0/TWRP/.twrps' not found.
I:Backup folder set to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/Redmi_A'
I:Mount: Unable to find partition for path '/etc'
I:Copied file /etc/recovery.fstab to /cache/recovery/recovery.fstab
I:Version number saved to '/cache/recovery/.version'
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 2047
I:PageManager::LoadFileToBuffer loading filename: '/twres/languages/en.xml' directly
parsing languageFile
parsing languageFile done
I:Translating partition display names
I:Backup folder set to '/data/media/0/TWRP/BACKUPS/Redmi_A'
I:Starting MTP
I:sending message to add 65537 '/data/media/0' 'Internal Storage'
I:Message sent, add storage ID: 65537 '/data/media/0'
I:sending message to add 65538 '/external_sd' 'Micro SD card'
I:Message sent, add storage ID: 65538 '/external_sd'
MTP Enabled
I:[MTP] Starting MTP
I:Switching packages (TWRP)
I:Set page: 'system_readonly'
I:[MTP] created new mtpserver object
I:[MTP] mtppipe add storage 65537 '/data/media/0'
E:[MTP] Failed to start usb driver!I:[MTP] mtppipe add storage 65538 '/external_sd'
I:operation_start: 'Toggle System Mount'
I:operation_end - status=0
I:Set page: 'main'
I:Set page: 'clear_vars'
I:Set page: 'main2'
I:Set page: 'main'
I:Set page: 'clear_vars'
I:Set page: 'main2'
I:Switching packages (TWRP)
I:Starting Adb Backup FIFO
I:Set page: 'main'
I:Set page: 'clear_vars'
I:Set page: 'main2'
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 5
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 2047
I:Set page: 'advanced'
I:Set page: 'filemanagerlist'
I:Set page: 'filemanageroptions'
I:Set page: 'filemanagerlist'
I:Set page: 'advanced'
I:Set page: 'main'
I:Set page: 'clear_vars'
I:Set page: 'main2'
E:[MTP] request read returned -1, errno: 5I:Set page: 'install'
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 5
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 0
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 2047
I:Set overlay: ''
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 5
I:TWFunc::Set_Brightness: Setting brightness control to 0
```

Comment: decryption relies on rom and firmware, in your case FBE uses login credentials from /data/misc/keystore and /data/system/locksettings.db you must restore and flash the matching system vendor modem etc

Comment: The syntax for decrypting TWRP from a command prompt is from a root shell or with TWRP a shell in general. Like: decrypt password :

 ` # decrypt /data with provided password` Specific pattern decrypt note
Use the table bellow to determine what your password will be: pattern logic here: https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html
Example: if your pattern is a "U" shape in the middle of the 5x5, enter `twrp decrypt '7<ABC>9'` in the terminal or ADB shell. Note that characters ;<>? are special to the shell and require backslash escaping or single quotes around the string.

Comment: Heyya thanks again.  I have `/vendor /recovery`  etc backed up from `stock` because even for custom `rom` they wont change ( backed up stock after `TWRP`  `Nandroid` backup ) . I did restore `/recovery /boot` from  previous Nandroid and the phone will still hang on boot logo. I dont have /system and /data backed up for this custom ROM.But TWRP is concerned with recovery so if I re-installed TWRP how do did that put me in a  boot logo freeze. Also of course I tried the TWRP decrypt command line thing using TWRP's guide nothing worked.

Comment: That'd had needed PIN + Key and something ran amuck on the key after TWRP reinstall Anyway a DD copy is of no use unless the data is decrypted and it wont backup via Nandroid either. Had to let it go

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar issue on a Nokia running a stock ROM. Basically Magisk module killed my phone and the TWRP won't allow decryption.

I was able to boot successfully to system again by.. Removing Magisk, because in the absence of Magisk, the Magisk modules shouldn't load and hence the system should boot just fine. I did that by flashing my stock boot image. Then I took a backup and did a reset.

You didn't specify which device you're using. But on an A/B device you can flash your original boot image from Havoc (from the exact same build you're currently on -- in case you installed any updates) on the active boot slot (double check that the boot slot didn't change while phone was trying to boot and fell back to the other slot when the active couldn't boot.

For the boot image, it is important for it to be from the exact same build, except the mismatched "Android OS level and OS version" can cause the phone to not boot.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help @Singh. Just updated my Q w comments I am on Redmi 8a

Comment: @user1874594 I couldn't figure out if the Redmi 8A is a project treble device and if it supports A/B partitions. Google is a tough place to find such info. You should still try booting your boot image from Havoc (matching the exact version that is currently installed on your phone) using - fastboot boot <filename>. If the boot image matches and the system is still capable of booting, it should go into Android system.

Comment: Redmi 8A is a project treble device yes. ' booting your boot image from Havoc' do you mean installation of Havoc again . I have a system image of havoc. that will sit in /system. I can install that via Recovrey. Oh and yes my previous Nandroid stock rom back up. I installed  /recovery from there. I didnt try /boot - would that help ?

Comment: @singhnsk Magisk will destroy FBE because there is no way to disable forceencrypt. unfortunately topjohnwu decided to destroy FDE also, if you want to disable forceencrypt for FDE you must use Magisk Manager v7.3.4. same [bug](https://github.com/Zackptg5/Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt/issues/12#issuecomment-590557688) is true for Zackptg5's Disable_Dm-Verity_ForceEncrypt

Comment: Howdy 'gain Alecxs. . To take home something - can I get access to `decrypted ` data ? ..should I `Nandroid /data ` ? and format proceed with rest OR there's nothing that can be done and I should save the sweat ---> format /data and do a fresh OS ?

Comment: how about this link https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-3/how-to/unencrypt-oxygenos-loosing-data-t3412228  how could this be done when your backup itself is  encrypted

Comment: the backup itself is of course unencrypted. you can't create backup on encrypted undecrypted device. Your only chance left is to restore all necessary partitions like it was before

Comment: ok then its a dead horse - clean slate. Wish I had `nandroid`ed everytime I thought on going on an adventure. The only thing between non booting ( stuck logo) OS and booting OS was that `TWRP` re-install. What Happened ? does TWRP  reinstall  mess with the meta `partition` that stores the encrypted key. I am posting the recovery log if that helps tell a story for anyone whom this may help .