# Android Recovery is loaded instead of TWRP after flashing TWRP with Odin

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, odin

There was [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143685/after-flashing-twrp-with-odin-nothing-happens-and-the-oem-recovery-is-still-the) here the solution to which was to boot into TWRP before booting android, so that TWRP isn't replaced by Android Recovery. I can press UP+Home+Power and go into recovery - I've not had an issue with that. But the trouble is that rather than showing TWRP it shows an android logo and it says it "updates the system" and then what comes up is Android Recovery instead of TWRP.

I'm using samsung's SM-g532g (galaxy j2 prime). It does not have an official TWRP apparently, so I'm trying the TWRP that [this site](https://www.androidinfotech.com/root-samsung-galaxy-j2-prime-sm-g532f-g-m-marshmallow/) suggested. I've tried it many ways: I've booted into recovery right after flashing TWRP, removed and replugged the battery and then booted into recovery, etc.

Comment: apparently TWRP is still replaced with stock recovery, or partition isn't covered by bootloader at all. you might flash some kernel fix to enable recovery from partition instead from ramdisk. see example [extract_elf_ramdisk](https://github.com/Dees-Troy/extract_elf_ramdisk) for Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230682

Comment: btw this is first samsung device with mediatek chipset i have ever seen, can you confirm it is **not** exynos or qualcomm? on mediatek devices you can use SP Flash Tool

Comment: @alecxs I think it is mediatek... Is using SP Flash Tool safe? I'm trying to backup my app data... Does SP Flash Tool wipe that data? I'm new to rooting, but I know Odin at least keeps that data safe.

Comment: SP Flash Tool is not safe, that's why the first thing you should do is full ROM dump and create your own scatter file based on current partition layout. for this i recommend 2nd Tool WwR MTK https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584

Comment: regarding your doubts, once you have scatter file you can flash (or read back) each single partition on it's own. that will allow you to patch boot.img with [Magisk Manager](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#downloads) (no TWRP needed)

Comment: @alecxs But patching boot.img means my device then wipes data, right? I don't want to lose my data...

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/sp-flash-tool-tutorial-to-install-twrp-custom-recovery-in-lenovo-k3-note.3346041/ also says that Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow needs a patched boot image for flashing custom recoveries with SP Flash Tool (and I think with Odin too).

Comment: @alecxs I think I would ask a silly question :) Do I have to unlock the bootloader in the process?

Comment: sure, as for all modifications. but on ancient samsung devices this is already done by toggle OEM unlocking in developer options, afaik no extra unlocking step required (no vaultkeeper)

Comment: if SP Flash Tool is too complicated try [mtk-su](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) bootless root method (risky on locked bootloader)

Comment: My device has dm-verity, does mtk-su work safely in this case? The link https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/amazing-temp-root-for-mediatek-armv8-2020-08-24.3922213/ says:  WARNING If you have a device with Android 6 or higher, it likely has dm-verity enabled. On such a device one does not simply remount the system partition as read/write. The remount command will probably fail. But if you succeed in forcing it somehow it will trigger dm-verity, which will result in a very bad day. Your device will become inoperable until you restore the stock system partition.

Comment: magisk will by-pass dm-verity so flashing magisk_patched.img from mtk-su will work. also magisk is [systemless-root](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info) (and afaik bootless-root has additional protections against modifying system)